# Tensorflow : tf.gather doesn't work on big arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm having an issue with my numpy array, which is of size (29000,200,1024)(7Go). Its the features of the images of my dataset.

Once loaded, my function receives the indexes to build the current batch as a tensor.
Unfortunately, using :

```
tf.gather(array, indices)
```

freezes. Though printing for example array[0] work instantly.
I tried to transform my numpy array with `convert_to_tensor` so I can use directly array_tensor(indice) but again, `convert_to_tensor` leads to a memory limit error.

Any work around ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing numpy array directly into tf op construction API converts it to `tf.constant` op which contains data in the op definition, so you are inlining the whole thing into GraphDef, subject to 2GB GraphDef limit.

To avoid this, create `var=tf.Variable(my_placeholder)` and initialize this variable by running `var.initializer, feed_dict={my_placeholder: np_array}`. This puts numpy array data directly into variable store.

Comment: Thank you for your very help full comment. 
Unfortunately, i dont have my session handler yet. I could fetch my variable later from the graph once i have my sess, but i wont have the placeholder anymore  for the feed dict... Any idea ? tyvm in advance

Comment: Save the placeholder into global variable?

Comment: Thanks this seems to work ! Unfortunately, opening the numpy array + putting it into a tensor make an OOM error. I'll need to make my batch in another way.